# How to setup a Virtual Host with Laravel 10.x with Vite and Livewire in XAMPP?

Tags: laravel, vite, virtualhost, laravel-livewire

I'm trying to setup a **Virtual Host in XAMPP for my Laravel 10.x project along with Vite and Livewire and MySQL**, the problem is I still need to always do the npm run dev. **Is there a way to set it up without using these commands such as this npm run dev for front-end or php artisan serve for back-end? My goal is to run my website in localhost without using these commands.** I have already checked questions and solutions here and in other sites but still no luck. Hope you can help me. **Thank you in advance.**

Answer (score -1):

You can try learn about start.sh and stop.sh scripts. I think it what you need.

Found some information here:

- https://www.inforbiro.com/blog/start-and-stop-scripts-for-xampp
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/428868/how-to-write-a-script-that-will-execute-xampp-start-and-stop (same problem as yours)

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate that! I think my problem is solved now, I just used Laragon instead of Xampp